# Getting crash using okhttp 2.7

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to use retrofit 1.9 in one of my project on Android Studio 2.0 on Ubuntu .
Those are my dependencies

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
  //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
```

As you can see I have commented this line and the app works

> //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'

Uncommenting that line and running the project the app crashes and I get this error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4660)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4290)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4232)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:140)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any idea?.
Thanks

**Edited and added:**

I am trying with

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

and the same error is getting:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.R$string

Comment: try with: compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'. This works for me

Comment: Yes I did , but In that case I will need retrofit 2.0 and we are working with 1.9

Comment: @JeCuRo use `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'` with `'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'`

Comment: thanks @IntelliJAmiya but I think that okhttp3 needs retrofit 2.0 and we are using 1.9

Comment: what about `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'` . & classpath `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'` ?

Comment: what dependency do you have in your library, meaning the class path ? ex: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Comment: @DadoZolic   I only  have this : classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

Comment: @JeCuRo did you set `retrofit:retrofit` 2.0 version ???? Use this , i hope it will helps you .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes I did , does not work :(

Comment: @JeCuRo strange case .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya absolutely agree

Comment: @JeCuRo set `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0` because `main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Works !!! with playservice 7.8.0 works!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @JeCuRo Glad to hear .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Whats your logcat throws

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.R$string at
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.(Unknown Source)

**[NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)**. This error is thrown when the **`Java Virtual Machine (JVM) or an instance of the ClassLoader`** class tries to load the definition of a class, but the definition could not be found. It extends the **LinkageError** class, which is used to indicate error cases, where a class has a dependency on some other class and that class has incompatibly changed after the compilation.

For your set up configurations 
you should use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

Then **Clean-Build-Restart-Sync** Your Project .